# Top Menu Alias Item for Kunema Forum Not Active on click

Tags: joomla, menu, alias

I have just installed Joomla version 2.5.9 and also the Kunema forum component version 2.0.4. I haven't installed any other components/modules/plugins.

I created a new top menu item called "Forum Sports" as a "Menu Alias Item" and pointed it to the Kunema Menu's "Forum" item (please see image below).

[image]

However, in the site when I click in the "Forum Sports" top menu item, it doesn't get active If I point this menu item to any other menu/article/page, the menu item gets active (please see images below).

[image]

[image]

How can I make the top menu item "Forum Sports" active when pointing to the Kunema Menu's Forum item?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Joomla assigns two different classes to menu items. If you're on the menu item page it will assign an `.active` and `.current` css class. Most templates (including Joomla's) menu items then base their styling on the `.current` class. To make the menu appear active just add in some extra css for the .current class into your templates css file :)

Comment: But that only is happening when I point the alias to Kunema. You mean adding "active" or "current" class using jQuery? Can you please explain with an example? Thank you.

Comment: No I mean the classes already exist if you take a look with firebug. Point to the alias item and you'll see there is a 'current' class and if you go to a article etc menu item then you'll see there is a 'active' and 'current' class. I'm sorry but I don't have an example to hand. I was building a site the other week with this issue before the client decided he didn't actually want a forum after all -.-